# Using list of values for custom function in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-custom-function

I'm writing a custom function in the Field Calculator (QGIS 2.18.5).

Creating a new function from `Function Editor` > `New file`, I'm able to start using a default function called `func`:

```py
"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def func(value1, feature, parent):
    return value1
```

At the beginning of the above code, I noticed this:

> *Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments*

Desiring to pass, for example, this list:

```py
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

as an input parameter, I tried to use `args=-1` instead of `args='auto'`:

```py
@qgsfunction(args=-1, group='Custom')
def my_func(my_list, feature, parent):
    return my_list
```

but I wasn't able to add this list for my custom function because I wrote it using an *invalid syntax*:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe I made some confusion about the using of `args`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would be interesting to see examples on how to use `args=-1` as I also couldn't find much information about it. But when you do use it, it seems as if it automatically treats the input argument as a list without you having to make it.

For example, if we use:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args=-1, group='Custom')
def my_func(my_list, feature, parent):
    val = my_list[1]
    return val
```

And use an expression like:

```
my_func('a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
```

It returns `'b'`:

[image: Result]

As `val` is returning the second item of `my_list`, it does seem that `my_func('a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')` is instead being read like `my_func(['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])`.

---

You can also see this by returning the input argument as a string using:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args=-1, group='Custom')
def my_func(my_list, feature, parent):
    return str(my_list)
```

And using the same expression:

```
my_func('a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')
```

[image: Second result]

We can see the input argument (which seemed to have been a list) being converted to a string.

---

---

*Hopefully a QGIS dev can enlighten us :)*

Comment: You are right, it seems that the usual Python syntax doesn't work for passing a list in a custom function. I didn't edit my answer after the further attempts, but you confirmed what I discovered today, i.e. that it isn't necessary typing the maximum number of input parameters for `args` but it would be enough setting a `-1` value. This operation exactly corresponds to the quote I enlightened in my original question. So, in my opinion, you answer is the best answer!

Comment: @mgri - I'm glad it was helpful but whether or not it is correct...I'm hoping a QGIS dev could post an answer and confirm what the behavour is =)

Comment: It should be like that: `args='auto'` for passing **any** number of parameters; `args=n` for passing **n** parameters; `args=-1` for passing a **list** of parameters.

Answer (score 5):

After some *trial-and-errors*, I found a working solution.

For passing a list as an argument, it would be enough setting the length of the list as a value for the `args` parameter. Then, since a list can't be returned by the function, it is necessary to specify a value from the list.

In my case, I need to rewrite the function in this way:

```py
@qgsfunction(args=3, group='Custom')
def my_func(my_list, feature, parent):
    val = my_list[1]
    return val
```

and call the function by directly inserting only a list as a parameter:

[image]

As desired, the function returns the second value from the list which is directly specified inside the parentheses (without recurring to the square brackets as it is usually done for lists).

Comment: i think the expression editor uses its own parser, I don't think it supports things like python lists and dicts in expressions (you can use them inside your python function, but might need to return them as strings for example).

Comment: @StevenKay do you think that my approach is wrong? Thinking about my solution, it will probably also work if I leave args='auto' (I didn't test it). For the return value, instead, I don't know if it is possible to return a list.